Manage UI for android Tablets & Foldable devices
res/drawable-(default)
res/drawable-ldpi/  
res/drawable-mdpi/  
res/drawable-hdpi/  
res/drawable-xhdpi/ 
res/drawable-xxhdpi/
res/drawable-xxxhdpi/
res/drawable-sw600dp/
res/drawable-sw720dp/

I am creating these layout.xml files for manage all screen sizes in portrait but not able to manage UI for 10-inches tablet and Galaxy/Pixel foldable devices.
So, what is the way to manage UI for both? Is I need to create another smallest screen width file?
If I make change in sw720dp layout.xml then I this layout make change for both device(TAB & Foldable).
As TAB screen height is higher than foldable devices. So, when I decrease the height for foldable, my tablet UI height spacing is increasing.
